# How to use OkHttp for multiple request to similar links in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-networking, okhttp, androidhttpclient

I'm trying to follow the example at the [official documentation of OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and I have no problem when posting 1 request, but **if the REST API I need to get info from has many different pages I can't make it work for different pages** for example, **theMovieDB API** has 5 pages for all filmography of Tom Hanks which are:

http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?with_cast=31&sort_by=release_date.asc&api_key=deea9711e0770caae3fc592b028bb17e&page=1

http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?with_cast=31&sort_by=release_date.asc&api_key=deea9711e0770caae3fc592b028bb17e&page=2

...

http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?with_cast=31&sort_by=release_date.asc&api_key=deea9711e0770caae3fc592b028bb17e&page=5

So I tried this approach without success:

```
public class ActorFilmographyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = ActorFilmographyActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private int totalPages = 5; //this is set at runtime with another OkHTTP call, lets say is five for simplicity

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    private List<String> JSONs = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actor_filmography);

        for (int pageNum=1; pageNum <= 4; pageNum++){
                try {
                    getResponseFor(pageNum);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

            for (String string : JSONs){
                Log.v(TAG, string);
            }
        }
    }

//This is the method I'm trying to use for multiple requests:

    private void getResponseFor(int pageNum) throws IOException {

        String url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?with_cast="
                + actor.getId() + "&sort_by=release_date.asc&api_key=" + API_KEY + "&page=" + pageNum;

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                JSONs.add(response.body().string());
            }
        });
```

How can I use OKHTTP for multiple request in android?

Comment: do you know what asynchronous implies?

Comment: @njzk2, that it's not at the same time, so it's in a different thread from GUI (which is mean thread) that's why im using OkHttp async call. Can you explain to me what I'm missing?

Comment: you are logging the content of your JSON list right after you have enqueued the requests. In most cases, the requests have not happened yet, hence you don't have anything to log.

Comment: @njzk2, thanks on answer so how do I work around while the requests finish?

Comment: since your requests are numbered, I would assume that the order matters. In which case, I would use an AsyncTask, and use the synchronous `Call.execute` instead of `enqueue` inside the `doInBackground`. One thing is sure, is that it is not in `onCreate` that you will be able to log the content of `JSON`